# Highcharts ShowFirstLabel and StartOnTick issue on xAxis

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts I am using dynamic data to generate x-axis with tickinterval as 1 day and minor tickinterval as 7 days.

Now, Suppose I need to show data from 1/3/2013 to 2/3/2013 then first label should display as 3/1 on first tick.

For that, I have set ShowFirstLabel and StartOnTick properties to true but in this case it is displaying First label as 12/31 instead of 1/3.

Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: can you reproduce the same in a js fiddle like thing

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your data is in UTC and you have GMT-X time. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ukhYs/1/ - you can set strict `min` and `max` for xAxis so it will be displayed with specific range.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        min: Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1),
        max: Date.UTC(2013, 2, 2)
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 5, 0), 123],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 7, 0), 121],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 9, 0), 112],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 12, 0), 152],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 15, 0), 125],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 16, 0), 123],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 19, 0), 132],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 2, 1, 23, 0), 102]
        ]
    }]
});
```